# how to add tab in notebook when using glade?

Tags: c, gtk, glade

When creating a `GtkNotebook` in Glade, I get 3 tabs by default. How can I add another tab?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Right-click on one of the tabs, and click "Insert page before" or "Insert page after".

Comment: Wow, all this time I thought it wasn't possible with Glade. I went through the Properties pane several times thinking "I must be missing something...."

Comment: @johannes : that was what im thinking about, before the savior eventually came...

Comment: Note: You have to right click on the widget in the tab (eg. a `Gtk.Label`), NOT on the spacing left and right of that widget. The latter shows a very similar menu with 'Insert after' and 'insert' before, but this refers to before/after the notebook, not the tab (and adds a space before/after the notebook).